# useState is needing to be pressed twice for an event to fire up in React/Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

In react/nextjs I have click Event for a button I'm trying to use setState and change an array and it fires up after two clicks
Here is the state array I have

`const [arrayClicked, setArrayClicked] = useState(["image-id-0", "image-id-1", "image-id-2", "image-id-3"]);`

`["image-id-0", "image-id-1", "image-id-2", "image-id-3"]` so the plan is to remove the first element and push in a new element from the back so it would be `["image-id-1", "image-id-2", "image-id-3", "image-id-4"]` then `["image-id-2", "image-id-3", "image-id-4", "image-id-5"]` etc

So if I use the JS mutation of the array and not the setState as:

```
arrayClicked.shift();
arrayClicked.push("image-id-4");
// I know that this is not the correct way of working with React but it works from the first click
```

this works directly from the first click of the button. But when I try to use setState I have to press twice for it fire up

this is my setState code:

```
const newIDImg = "image-id-4"; // example normally they are actual ID values for images
setArrayClicked(prev => {
  const prevArray = prev.filter(val => {
    return val !== prev[0];
  });
  return [...prevArray, newIDImg];
});

// even if I try slice same problem it fires up after second click
setArrayClicked(prev => [
  ...prev.slice(1, prev.length),
  newIDImg
]);
```

Here is the full set of code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// props.product.images is 13 in length so index from 1 to 13 so keeping it as read only

const [displaySmallerImages, setDisplaySmallerImages] = useState(props.product.images.slice(0, 4));
const [arrayClicked, setArrayClicked] = useState(['image-id-0', 'image-id-1', 'image-id-2', 'image-id-3']);

const handleRightClick = () => {
    // example props.product.images is 13 in length
    const exampleFakeIndex = 3;
    let newIDImg, tempArray;

    if (props.product.images[exampleFakeIndex + 1] !== undefined) {
        newIDImg = props.product.images[exampleFakeIndex + 1].id;
        // arrayClicked.shift(); // TODO FIX THIS TO USE setArrayClicked INSTEAD!!
        // arrayClicked.push(newIDImg); // TODO FIX THIS TO USE setArrayClicked INSTEAD!!
        setArrayClicked(prev => {
            const prevArray = prev.filter(val => {
                return val !== prev[0];
            });
            return [...prevArray, newIDImg];
        });
        // AS displaySmallerImages IS ARRAY OF OBJECT THIS IS A HELPER FUNCTION WHICH DISPLAYS THEM AS
        tempArray = helperArrayNewSetOfFours(arrayClicked, props.product.images);
        // helperArrayNewSetOfFours just returns an array of object of {id, imgName, imgData}
        setDisplaySmallerImages(tempArray);
    } else {
        newIDImg = props.product.images[0].id;
        // arrayClicked.shift(); // TODO FIX THIS TO USE setArrayClicked INSTEAD!!
        // arrayClicked.push(newIDImg); // TODO FIX THIS TO USE setArrayClicked INSTEAD!!

        setArrayClicked(prev => [
            ...prev.slice(1, prev.length),
            newIDImg
        ]);

        tempArray = helperArrayNewSetOfFours(arrayClicked, props.product.images);
        setDisplaySmallerImages(tempArray);
    }
}
```

The helperFunction `helperArrayNewSetOfFours` is basically a function with returns an array of object for the new array of objects to be displayed and then passed to the `displaySmallerImages` array through the `setDisplaySmallerImages` incase you want to see what the `helperArrayNewSetOfFours` is:

```
    const helperArrayNewSetOfFours = (oldFour, fullArraySize) => {
        const arrayTemp = [];
        oldFour.forEach((val, ind) => {
            fullArraySize.forEach(img => {
                if (val === img.idImage) {
                    arrayTemp.push({
                        id: img.id,
                        imgName: img.imgName,
                        imgData: img.imgData
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        return arrayTemp;
    }
```

returns:

```
//THE OLD
array = [ 
 { id: "image-id-1", imgName: "name1", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER },
 { id: "image-id-2", imgName: "name2", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER },
 { id: "image-id-3", imgName: "name3", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER },
 { id: "image-id-4", imgName: "name4", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER }
];

// The new array because of the helper function returns
//THE NEW IT RETURNS!!
array = [ 
 { id: "image-id-2", imgName: "name2", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER },
 { id: "image-id-3", imgName: "name3", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER },
 { id: "image-id-4", imgName: "name4", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER },
 { id: "image-id-5", imgName: "name5", imgData: ARRAY BUFFER }
];
```

So why does setState force two click before the values registers and it fires up? While array mutation JS the `.shift() and .push()` fires up directly from the first click? How can I make the setState to work directly from the first click?

Comment: Ranting about closure in your question will probably not get the best response from the community.  I just took a look at the suggested duplicate and the problem and solution appear to be the same as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

For anyone who wants to know I learned from this that you cannot use setState from the result of a state you just setted.

For example I have setArrayClicked which I am setting it's state with new values then I wanted to place arrayClicked into setDisplaySmallerImg which caused the event to fire after a second click. Because `arrayClicked` is the yet the old values and setState is asynchronous so the new values haven't been stored yet.

So instead of this:

```
        setArrayClicked(prev => [
            ...prev.slice(1, prev.length),
            newIDImg
        ]);

        tempArray = helperArrayNewSetOfFours(arrayClicked, props.product.images);
        setDisplaySmallerImages(tempArray);
```

I done:

```
// made a temp tempFour array
let tempFour = [];

            tempFour = [...arrayClicked.slice(1, forClick.length), newIDImg];
// so here I rather using the tempFour array and putting that value into the setDisplaySmallerImages
// then as well setting the setArrayClicked with the tempFour array so for the next click I have new values in the arrayClicked so everything is going smoothly from the first click now!
            setArrayClicked(tempFour);

            tempArray = helperArrayNewSetOfFours(tempFour, props.product.images);
            setDisplaySmallerImages(tempArray);
```